# python device crash left my code with <<<<<<<<<<<<HEADER

Tags: python

I have my own Python script running on a Pi3, it runs constantly in the background in a screen session, most of the time its waiting in a time.sleep() function.

I had a power cut and of course my Pi had a sudden power loss, everything was fine except my Python script was broken, it had been ammended to look like:

```
<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<HEADER
My Code
=======================
My Code
```

I realise no system is supposed to stand up well to sudden power loss, Im just trying to understand if this is an expected outcome, is it a design feature, or is it just random?

Everything is working fine, I just deleted the directory and git cloned again.

Comment: Looks like the result of a merge conflict...

Comment: OK that makes sense, I was messing with git around the same time